Can someone please create the tags "hypergeometric-distribution" and "random-number-generation"
I think these are good categories to use, and see a number of posts that should use them instead of more ambiguous (like "probability-distribution) or incorrect (like hypergeometric-function) tags.
I don't have enough reputation-points to do this, can anyone help here?

This question belongs on [meta], not here; there's a big question for tag requests there you can make your case at.

I don't have points to post there.

My two cents: random variate generation, especially, would be worthwhile to add. It’s a gap.

I'd also like a tag for inverse-transform-sampling described here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling
As mentioned in the article, it goes by several names: inversion sampling, the inverse probability integral transform, the inverse transformation method, or the Smirnov transform.
